# COM registration error in Visual Studio 2008 setup project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, com, setup-project, outlook-redemption

I'd like to register [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) as an isolated COM component using a Visual Studio 2008 setup project. After adding Redemption.dll to my setup project, if I choose either vsdrfCOMRelativePath or vsdrfCOM options in Properties > Register, I get the following error.

> Exception EAccessViolation in module msvbver.dll at 0000A15F.
>   Access violation at address 467DA15F in module 'msvbver.dll'. 
>   Read of address 000000CC.

Does this error mean the problem is with my Visual Studio setup or does it mean that there is something wrong with the way Redemption.dll works?

(Note: Selecting the vsdrfCOMSelfReg option works, but is not what I want to do.)

Answer (score 1):

Redemption does register via self-registration in terms of `DllRegisterServer` (invoked manually via `regsvr32 redemption.dll`), which should translate to `vsdrfSelfReg`.
As far as i recall you can still run into problems if the dependencies of the self-registering module are not available when registering.

Comment: I know that Redemption is self-registering. I'd like to register it as an isolated (reg-free) COM component, however.